# Authentication issue in Burp suite

Tags: security, penetration-testing, burp, penetration-tools

I am getting alerts for authentication in Burp Suite. 
I have already followed the suggestion given in burp suite support site but it seems not working.
How to resolve this ? How to see the request which is passing and not getting authenticated.

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQpD1.png)

Comment: Can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

Turn of the NTLM configuration in Burpsuite

Comment: Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.